# How does 'find()' work in a 'std::set<std::pair<int,int>>'?

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

I'm solving the LeetCode problem 'Path Crossing', where I use a `set<pair<int,int>>`, trying to find whether the point `x,y` is already in the path or not. But I don't get the desired result.

```cpp
bool isPathCrossing(string s) {
    set <pair <int, int>> st;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    st.insert(make_pair(x,y));
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'N') y++;
        else if(s[i] == 'W') x++;
        else if(s[i] == 'S') y--;
        else x--;
        pair <int, int> pr = make_pair(x, y);
        if(st.find(pr) != st.end()) return false;
        st.insert(pr);
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Does the `find()` method work only for the first element of the `pair`, or for both elements?

Comment: RTM https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair, look at the overloaded non-member functions https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp, it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, when `find()` is comparing 2 `pair` objects, both `first` and `second` values are looked at, not just the `first` value.

That said, the reason you are not getting the desired result is simply because **you did not follow the instructions** that LeetCode gave you:

- *Your `return` values are backwards.*

  You need to return `true` if your loop finds an existing point in the `set`, otherwise return `false` if the entire `string` is consumed without finding a match.
- *Your movements of the `x` coordinate are backwards.*

  West moves to the left, and East moves to the right, so you need to *decrease* `x` on `'W'` and *increase* `x` on `'E'`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
bool isPathCrossing(string s) {
    set <pair <int, int>> st;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    st.insert(make_pair(x,y));
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'N') y++;
        else if(s[i] == 'W') x--;
        else if(s[i] == 'S') y--;
        else x++;
        pair <int, int> pr = make_pair(x, y);
        if(st.find(pr) != st.end()) return true;
        st.insert(pr);
    } 
    return false;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/6Shgwx)

Comment: "West moves to the left, and East moves to the right"  That depends on if you're looking at the ground or the sky.  Either system can be used to solve problems, as long as the logic is internally consistent.

Comment: @BenVoigt perhaps, but in THIS case, the instructions provided by the LeetCode problem clearly demonstrate that West moves to left and East moves to the right.